# Ubuntu 17.04 - Malayalam fonts are too small

Tags: fonts, language-support, malayalam

Particularly in Facebook and Gmail, Malayalam fonts are tiny and not readable.
Also, combination of letters is not working.

[image]

What can I do about this?

[image]

Comment: Can You provide a screenshot of the issue ? Also if this is an browser zooming the font - You can reset it in Chrome using `ctrl+0` shortcut or clicking on the zoom icon inside the search bar (on the right) and `reset` it.

Comment: I am using chrom and Mozilla. Both browse has same issue.  Zooming not solving issue. The fonts are smaller than English Fonts.

Comment: @riazrafeeque In Firefox type `about:preferences` in the address bar and hit enter. Then navigate to **Language and Appearance**, select **Advanced**, in "**Fonts for:**" select "*Malayalam*" and try to increase the size. Also try changing fonts.

Comment: attached full window screenshot.

the script in malayalam got issues like spelling error (combining different letters), but when same words are copy paste to libre all are in order.

Comment: @pomsky , i tried in firefox. but not working .  Font size in other pages are increase. but font size in malayalam in Gmail not incresed. screenshot attached.

Comment: @pomsky Yest, tried every combination. But Gmail and Fb are same , fonts are too small

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is an issue with the default font used to render malayalam, 'Meera' in my case. You can check with `LANG=ml_IN fc-match` in the terminal.
To change the default font used system-wide:

1. Create a file : `~.config/fontconfig/conf.d/50-my-malayalam.conf`
2. Add the following in the contents:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
   <fontconfig>
   <!-- Malayalam (ml) -->
   <match target="font">
           <test name="lang" compare="contains">
                   <string>ml</string>
           </test>
           <alias>
                   <family>sans-serif</family>
                   <prefer>
                           <family>Noto Sans Malayalam</family>
                   </prefer>
           </alias>
   </match>

   <match target="font">
           <test name="lang" compare="contains">
                   <string>ml</string>
           </test>
           <alias>
                   <family>serif</family>
                   <prefer>
                           <family>Rachana</family>
                   </prefer>
           </alias>
   </match>
   <!-- Malayalam (ml) ends -->
   </fontconfig>
   ```

> I used 'Noto Sans Malayalam' and 'rachana' here, replace it with a font you like.

source: https://thottingal.in/blog/2018/08/10/how-to-customize-malayalam-fonts-in-linux/

How i fixed this in Firefox only:
Preferences > Fonts & Colors > Set default font as 'Noto Sans Malayalam' (This one increased the font size in my case; Tested on Facebook and YouTube comments).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the fonts in chrome settings to various malayalam language options available there. And some fonts (Anjaliold, Lohit etc..) solved the problem for me in Chrome in Ubuntu 18.04. Now the malayalam and english letters are looking almost same font size in websites like youtube etc.

Comment: Your answer only deals with Chrome, an application. Not the whole system as the OP asked. Chrome is not even part of the default Ubuntu install.